# SharedPreferences is not giving the correct position value?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm using the following method of SharedPreferences to get the index of a clicked item of a List using RecyclerView adapter , when retrieving the position from SharedPreferences it is not giving me the correct index , instead it gives another random index number, for example **when I click 5 the pos value should be 4** , but I get a random number like 12 or 7 etc.

**Hint**: when I hover over commit , it says I can use apply instead of commit, I did that but it didn't have any effect.

How can I fix this ?

Storing data into `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).commit();
```

Retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences getPref = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int pos = getPref.getInt("position",0);
```

**Update**

**RecyclerView.Adapter**

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder> {


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String item);
    }


    private ArrayList<String> episodeslist;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<String> episodeslist, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.episodeslist = episodeslist;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planet_row, parent,false);
        PlanetViewHolder vh=new PlanetViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
        tv.setText(episodeslist.get(position));
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bg, 0, 0, 0);

        vh.bind(episodeslist.get(position), listener);

        //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.planetimage);
        vh.text.setText(episodeslist.get(position).toString());
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return episodeslist.size();
    }



    public class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        }
        public void bind(final String item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getPosition();
                     listener.onItemClick(item);

                    SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are putting the correct position? Try logging that position before putting it into `setPref`.

Comment: show WHEN you are storing `position`, post some adapters code and click listener implementation

Comment: Thanks, yes I can confirm that I get the correct position , I double checked that , before posting here, I get the value like this `int position = getPosition();` just before applying `SharedPreferences` and it is working very well.

Comment: So the position you print with `getPosition()` is what you want to store but then it's not stored that value, right? Could you post where you set the preference?

Comment: Thanks , post updated with added `RecyclerView.Adapter` code

Comment: personally I don't se any flaws, maybe you are obtaining `position` from preferences inside `onItemClick` method, before shared prefs `commit` gets called? so you are getting previously clicked value, not current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say two options :

Change your `PlanetViewHolder` to receive a position

```
public void bind(final String item, final Int position, final OnItemClickListener listener)
```

Then from your `onBindViewHolder` you do :

vh.bind(episodeslist.get(position), position, listener);

May look like it's the same, but at least you are passing the position where you tap.

Also what you could do is add another parameter in your `OnItemClickListener` with the position and in your implementation log this or print to check if that's the correct then you store it in `SharedPreferences`.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String item, Int position);
    }
```

Since you add the position in `ViewHolder` you could do :

```
listener.onItemClick(item, position); // <-- Not the getPosition()
```

Comment: I gave the first option a try still the same.

Comment: I your viewHolder you don't call the `getPosition()` and use the one that comes from `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: Could you store first in `SharedPreference` and then do the `onItemClick`? Perhaps the problem is that you get the old position...

Comment: Thank you so much problem solved , storing SharedPreference first did the trick.